# Post data into custom Google Analytics metric from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've created custom dimension `streamIdMismatch` and custom metric 
with same name `streamIdMismatch`

[image]

Also, I've created custom report which is based on my dimension and metric:

[image]

And now I want to post some data into my report, I use this `javascript` code:

```
var metricValue = '123';
ga('set', 'metric1', metricValue);
```

But in the report I see nothing...

Comment: Have you waited long enough for the data to process into standard reports? Also, have you verified your hits are sending your CD and CM values?

Comment: Remember that set does not send the value. You need a hit (pageview, event, timing, transaction etc.) after the set call. It is not obvious from your example that there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Eike Pierstorff` and `Vinoaj` are right. Setting a custom dimension or metric does nothing. You have to associate them with a hit:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#collection

> Unlike other types of data, custom dimensions and metrics are sent to
>   Analytics as parameters attached to other hits, like pageviews,
>   events, or ecommerce transactions. As such, custom dimension or metric
>   values need to be set before a tracking call is made in order for that
>   value to be sent to Analytics.

For instance:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
var metricValue = 123;
ga('set', 'metric1', metricValue);
ga('send','event', 'My Category',','metric1',metricValue);
```

or:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
var metricValue = 123;
ga('set', 'metric1', metricValue);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Also, if you are only setting the `custom metric` but create a report including a `custom dimension` which you have haven't set you might run into some unexpected reporting issues.

Answer (score 0):

The custom metric must be a positive integer ([reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#metric)).

I would try the following code instead:

```
var metricValue = 123;
ga('set', 'metric1', metricValue);
```